# Getting value error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to use Isolation forests as a classifier in python 2.7 anaconda framework and here is my sample code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
import pandas
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import set_printoptions

filename1 = 'path/Cleanedinput.csv'
dataframe1 = read_csv(filename, names=names,low_memory=False)
Xtrain = dataframe1.values
Xtrain.shape
(996405L, 16L)
Xtrain[0:2]

array([[1744121620.0, 2590000000.0, '44846', '39770', '6', '100', 1L, '5', '290', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '46846', 12.9833, 77.5833], 
[1724121520.0, 2260000000.0, '12337', '31772', '6', '100', 1L, '1', '54', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '41637', 23.4833, 24.123]], dtype=object)

clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=10, random_state=rng)
clf.fit(X_train)
```

My Xtrian array looks like

```
array([[1744121620.0, 2590000000.0, '44846', '39770', '6', '100', 1L, '5', '290', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '46846', 12.9833, 77.5833], 
[1724121520.0, 2260000000.0, '12337', '31772', '6', '100', 1L, '1', '54', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '41637', 23.4833, 24.123]], dtype=object)
```

but I am getting value error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0a80fca9c379> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.fit(X_train)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\iforest.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    157         # ensure_2d=False because there are actually unit test checking we fail
    158         # for 1d.
--> 159         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csc'], ensure_2d=False)
    160         if issparse(X):
    161             # Pre-sort indices to avoid that each individual tree of the

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: -
```

Is there something I am missing in terms of data type

Comment: how many lines long is your csv? the error says you are trying to convert `"-"` to a float. You probably have `"-"` in your csv. I don't see that in the first two lines though

Comment: I'm not sure how it might have happened, but it appears that one of your input strings is no more than a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the data in `Xtrain` variable that you have, is being represented as `Strings` rather than `numerical` values .

In the `Xtrain` that you provided

```
array([[1744121620.0, 2590000000.0, '44846', '39770', '6', '100', 1L, '5', '290', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '46846', 12.9833, 77.5833],  [1724121520.0, 2260000000.0, '12337', '31772', '6', '100', 1L, '1', '54', 60L, '1', 1L, '-6', '41637', 23.4833, 24.123]], dtype=object)
```

`'44846'  , '39770 ..etc` is a string value.

Look at the `dtype` of this `Xtrain` , its an `object` , convert the dtype to `float/int` and it should work.